# Macho - remove a LOAD COMMAND from iOS binary

Tags: decompilation, hopper, dynamic-linking

I want to remove a `LOAD_COMMAND` from my iOS app binary.

I tried [jtool](http://www.newosxbook.com/tools/jtool.html):

```
jtool -rC 3 my_app_binary
```

This worked when I was removing a dynamic library.  But it generated an empty binary file and the original binary was not altered when I wanted to remove:

```
LC 03: LC_SEGMENT_64          Mem: 0x100007000-0x100007000  __RESTRICT
```

I found the same with [optool](https://github.com/alexzielenski/optool).  I could delete a `dylib` but not this `RESTRICT` load command.

Next stop is Hopper...

Answer (score 1):

If you compile [optool](https://github.com/alexzielenski/optool) from source, there is a new `unrestrict` flag.

`optool unrestrict -t Payload/MY_APP.app/MY_APP`

This worked. Load command removed.

There is even a nice guide explaining how to compile from source, [here](http://www.mopsled.com/2016/build-optool-osx/).